# Is the moment generating function of the gamma density $g(t)=(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t})^n$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, gamma-distribution

My book defines the gamma density as the following:
$$f_X(x)=\lambda (\lambda x)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x}/(n-1)!$$
And has the moment generating function of this density as $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda +t}$. Is this a typo, as from [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245279/moment-generating-function-of-a-gamma-distribution) and my own computation I think the MGF for this form of the gamma density should be $(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t})^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

For that special type of gamma distribution, another name for it is [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution).

It is the formula of the sum of $n$ independent exponential distributions, hence we need to raise the power.